# Remove white spaces added in nvim on save

Tags: neovim

I am using LazyVim to configure neovim, I have turned off format on save and now when I save white spaces are added at specific places which I don't want. How can I stop this white spaces to be added on save
[image]

Comment: vim questions should be asked on https://vi.stackexchange.com/ You should delete this and ask there.

Answer (score 0):

With a Neovim autocommand in Lua, you could trim white spaces at the end of lines when saving a file.

In the following code, this autocommand is used only for some defined filetypes (C/C++, Lua, Java...). You could use `pattern='*'` to run this autocommand on every file. Add it in your Lua configuration.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('FileType', {
  group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('trim_whitespaces', { clear = true }),
  desc = 'Trim trailing white spaces',
  pattern = 'bash,c,cpp,lua,java,go,php,javascript,make,python,rust,perl,sql,markdown',
  callback = function()
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('BufWritePre', {
      pattern = '<buffer>',
      -- Trim trailing whitespaces
      callback = function()
        -- Save cursor position to restore later
        local curpos = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)
        -- Search and replace trailing whitespaces
        vim.cmd([[keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e]])
        vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor(0, curpos)
      end,
    })
  end,
})
```

Comment: inplace of autocmd I have used vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd because autocmd is not defined, but this still does not work.

Comment: Fix my code for `autocmd` => `vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd` (alias in my code, suppressed here).